# Retrieving images from mysql and displays on webpage

Tags: python, mysql

I used the following code:

```
import MySQLdb
import base64
from PIL import Image
import cStringIO

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="root",
                     db="test")
# select statement with explicit select list and where clause instead of select * ...
sql1='select img from images where id=1'  
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
data2=cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
db.close()

file_like=cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(data2[0][0]))

img1=Image.open(file_like,mode='r').convert('RGB')
img1.show()
```

Everything works well.

How can I display these images using an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use python web framework like Flask or Django to create views for the web.

Then you can import your this module into the python web framework, either flask or Django to serve the images to web pages.